# How to distinguish drawable folders for 480x800 and 540x960 screen resolutions?

Tags: android, android-layout, drawable

I want to prepare seperate drawables for 480x800 and 540x960 screen resolutions in my app. 
Since there are both classified as `hdpi` drawables I can't see straightforward way to do this. 
Should I do it programatically in all layouts (I hope not)? 
Can I create two folders:
`drawable-hdpi` 
`drawable-hdpi-540x960`?

What's best solution here? 
I want to be compatible with Android >= 2.3.3 so I can't use new screen qualifiers.

Thanks.

**EDIT:** 
I want to have different set of icons for these base resolutions: 
320x480 
480x800 
540x960 
720x1280

Comment: My question to you would be why you need to distinguish between them?

Comment: I was asked to put bigger images on such resolution. Is it possible?

Comment: 540x960 is not hdpi. put images in drawable-xhdpi.

Comment: And what about difference between 540x960 and 720x1280 screens?

Comment: "Since there are both classified as hdpi drawables" -- neither are "classified as hdpi". Density refers to dots per inch. Resolution refers to dots. You can have 480x800 in any size. "I want to have different set of icons for these base resolutions" -- that makes no sense whatsoever. I can see having different icons for different screen sizes, and I can see having different versions of the same icon for different screen densities. Different icons based on resolution is bizarre.

Comment: @CommonsWare Let's take into account two phones : Samsung Galaxy S2 with pixel density 1.5 and screen size 480x800px and HTC One S with pixel density 1.5 and screen size 540x960px. How can I provide two different drawables for them using drawable-x qualifiers?

Comment: @Piotr: I wouldn't "provide two different drawables for them". I would use one drawable for them, because they are the same in terms of screen size and density. You are welcome to do work in Java code, to detect the actual resolution and switch to some different drawable by name or something, if you feel that there is some critical need for you "to have different set of icons for these base resolutions".

Comment: You don't. There's no reason to do so. The images will appear at roughly the same size on both displays. You should only worry about different qualifiers for different densities. And @Padma, resolution alone does not determine density. Without knowing the physical screen size you cannot say that 540x960 is one density or the other.

Comment: Guys, trust me, it's not my decision. I wouldn't do that either, but I am forced to. So question is if I have to work with Java to accomplish    it.

Comment: In that case the answer is yes, you will have to do it programmatically. I'm going to guess the designers requesting this work in iOS development? You need to explain to them that that mindset doesn't work for Android.

Comment: @kcoppock actually I was looking for progammatic solution but yours was way better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

normal drawable folders which are generated in the project structure are all used for all kind of devices as per device density. If you want to use big sized images for 540X960 then you use drawable-large (large specifier) with same name as used in drawables used for phone. large specifier will differentiate your drawables for Big resolution devices.

Comment: I meant 540x960px and 480x800 pixels. They are both medium size.

Comment: sorry I expected you want big sized images for large devices like tablet. But the thing is only density differs in medium size devices and almost all devices will have same size icons with density vary. I want you to revise your question you want to ask.

Answer (score -1):

You have to name the drawable as per your pixel density and the screen size. The calculation is here...

dpi = sqrt (540^2+960^2) / 4.3"(Device size) = ~256 dp = px / (dpi / 160) = 540 / (dpi / 160) = 330

The drawable will be named as drawable-sw330dp. I have tested this. And this works good. No problem with other drawables either. Layout Will be layout-sw330dp

Or you can try this by drawable-sw540p. I haven't tested it yet. But I guess it will work good. Layout Will be layout-sw540p